# how to replace a sequence of characters with a newline?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I'd like to replace all instances of `&#34;,&#34;` with a newline.

The input is in file.txt:

```
category&#34;:&#34;Natura&#34;,&#34;URL&#34;:&#34;https://site.com/image/image.image_small.jpg?43454645&#34;,&#34;HELLO
```

I wish to end up with (OUTPUT NEW-FILE.TXT):

```
category&#34;:&#34;Natura
URL&#34;:&#34;https://site.com/image/image.image_small.jpg?443454645
HELLO
```

The command could be: `sed`, `echo`, and/or `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No big deal with `sed`:

```
sed 's/&#34;,&#34;/\n/g' file
```

`s/search/replace/g` searches for the term `search` and replaces it with the term `replace`. The `g` indicates that the search-replace should be performed globally, thus multiple times per line.